# Is it possible to run laravel 5.3 web application in php 5.5 ?

Tags: php, laravel, version

I developed web app in laravel 5.3 but my client's hosting php version is php-5.5
And they can not update
Is it possible to run laravel 5.3 in php 5.5?

Comment: Cannot update, or won't update? PHP 5.5 is now EOL and unsupported. Recommend upgrading to 7.0/1. But also no, Laravel requires 5.6 for 5.3.

Comment: laravel requires 5.6 or higher for 5.3 :) which is mean that php 7 will be ok

Answer (score 2):

the answer seems to be no

according to version 5.3.x [composer.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.3.30/composer.json) :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"
},
```

Comment: yeah, you cannot use laravel 5.3 with PHP lower than 5.6.4

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot,check out server requirements according to laravel 5.3 documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3